# Regex question for htaccess redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect

http://mydomain.com/2011/09/anything

(where 2011 is any year, and 09 is any month, and anything is anything!)

over to:

http://mydomain.com/special-folder/anything

Could someone help me out with the regex for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/(.*)$    http://mydomain.com/special-folder/$1
```